# Unwanted margin removal

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

Why are there orange and yellow lines? I think my orange children element must cover yellow parent element and blue children element must cover orange parent element.

Look at this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/taurus790/XFSSR/6/) in jsfiddle. The code below is not full.

HTML:

```
<SECTION ID="Middle_Col">
    <ARTICLE ID="Article_1">
    </ARTICLE>

</SECTION>
```

CSS:

```
 BODY {
width: 1024px;
background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, how exactly do you want the layout?

Comment: [SO](http://jsfiddle.net/taurus790/KsjYW/). edited with 1st answer.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue you want to utilize a css reset, i was able to replicate and solve your issue using the popular Erik Meyer's css reset below

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

the conflict has to do with some of the new html5 elements behaving badly specifically when they interact with containing elements' margin inconsistencies.  here erik ensures all of the html 5 elements have display:block; and standardizes padding and margins.

[you can read more about his work here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: What if the OP *wants* the margins?

Comment: was responding to a question that seems to have since been modified - OP stated he wanted margins gone

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of *margin collapse*.  If you add a border to the `#Middle_Col #Article_1` element, the yellow is no longer visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/XFSSR/10/

Altering the overflow property (`overflow: hidden`, etc.) can also inhibit margin collapse.

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to
>   separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing

Here's an article with some really nice diagrams:  http://www.seifi.org/css/understanding-taming-collapsing-margins-in-css.html

Comment: this is some useful stuff to know - ive always had a basic understanding of what was happening to cause this issue and how to correct it but never a full detailed explanation! thanks for this